# Padding columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, padding

I have 2 dataframes like this,

```
df1

    0   1   2   3   4   5   category
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   foo
1   4   5   6   5   6   7   bar
2   7   8   9   5   6   7   foo1
```

and

```
df2

    0   1   2   category
0   1   2   3   bar
1   4   5   6   foo
```

Shape of df1 is `(3,7)` and shape of df2 is `(2,4)`.

I want to reshape df2 to `(2,7)` (as per first dataframe df1 columns) keeping the last column same.

```
df2 

    0   1   2  3  4  5  category
0   1   2   3  0  0  0  bar
1   4   5   6  0  0  0  foo
```

Comment: You could just do `df2 = df2.iloc[:-2]` to omit the last line. Or do I misunderstood your question?

Comment: literally just add 3 more columns and fill them with 0s

Comment: Hmm No...In originally, the dataframe shapes are `(4290, 2970)` and `(1241, 3102)` and It will change the shape for different experiments. I want to create something dynamic, such that, dataframe having less columns will give pad the columns with zero according to the dataframe having more columns. In this case, first dataframe will pad 132 columns with zero.

Comment: Will it always be the first columns that will be the same and the last one or other combinations (e.g., columns 0, 1, 3, 5 in df1) possible?

Comment: @Mr.T No first columns should remain same, and last one. I just want to make sure both dataframe should have same number of columns. Rows can be different, but the last column should be category and number of columns of both dataframe should remain same. So if there is a difference between number of columns I will pad them with zero.

Comment: Just to make sure - column names will not differ, no? df2 can't have column names like 101, 102, 103, category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that dataframe having less columns will pad the columns with `zero` according to the dataframe having more columns, then you can try [`DataFrame.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) on `axis=1` to `align` the columns of two dataframes keeping the rows unchanged:

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print(df2)

    0  1  2  3  4  5 category
 0  1  2  3  0  0  0      bar
 1  4  5  6  0  0  0      foo
```

Comment: @AdityaParikh Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `.shape[0]` to get the # of rows from each dataframe. and `.shape[1]` to get the # of columns from each dataframe.
2. Use these logically with `insert` to only include the required rows and make the required columns `0`:

---

```
s1, s2 = (df1.shape[1]), (df2.shape[1])
s = s1-s2
[df2.insert(s-1, s-1, 0) for s in range(s2,s1)]

    0   1   2   3   4   5   category
0   1   2   3   0   0   0   bar
1   4   5   6   0   0   0   foo
```

Another method using `iloc`:

```
s1, s2 = (df1.shape[1] - 1), (df2.shape[1] - 1)
df3 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[:, :-1],
                 df1.iloc[:df2.shape[0]:, s2:s1],
                 df2.iloc[:, -1]], axis=1)
df3.iloc[:, s2:s1] = 0

    0   1   2   3   4   5   category
0   1   2   3   0   0   0   bar
1   4   5   6   0   0   0   foo
```

Comment: @David Erickson, Sir Thank you for solution. But actually changes number of rows also. For example, I have a df1 having shape of `(40, 20)` and df2 having shape of `(10,30)` then, df1 should be change to `(40,30)`. But in your solution df3 also changes with the number of rows i.e. `(10,30)` . We don't want to change number of rows.

Comment: @AdityaParikh I see where I have gone wrong and have corrected my answer.